# Unable to create custom theme with Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I am trying to write a custom theme on an Orchard setup I have on my local machine. I need the source code as we will be checking code in-and-out of source control. I have downloaded the source code for Orchard 1.6 from CodePlex (http://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets?branch=default).

I have a basic site up and running. However, I want to create a custom theme. Based on this tutorial: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-new-theme, I need to use the codegen command line tool. My challenge is, when I attempt to execute the orchard.exe command-line tool found in /src/Tools/Orchard/bin/Release/Orchard.exe. I receive an error that says:

*Initializing Orchard session. (This might take a few seconds...)
Error:
  Directory "C:\Website\src\Tools\Orchard\bin\Release" doesn't seem to contain an Orchard installation*

I don't get it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the wrong orchard common line tool.

The one you need to run is in  `~\src\Orchard.Web\bin\`

Comment: One more related question:  When I edit the theme in Visual Studio. It seems like my changes never take. When I update the theme in Visual Studio, what do I have to do to get the changes to take effect?

Comment: I'd double check to be sure that your changes are being made to the files within the Themes folder that is a child of the Visual Studio solution root.